# Avatar image: store in database or on CDN?

Tags: sql-server, database, image, cdn, data-storage

Avatar image: store in database or on CDN?

Ps( avatar is the users profile photo)

Comment: How can anyone give a meaningful answer with no details about the situation? A CDN may be overkill or the (single) database may be inadequate, but without any details, either could be the right or wrong advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why store it yourself when you can just use http://en.gravatar.com/ or similar like Stack Overflow uses?

Answer (score 2):

If you store in database, the image file are uncacheable, because user browser will cache the image file by the link so that it don`t have to download the file again.

Normally, user avatar files are store in file dictionary, so it have a permalink for the image file.

You can use CDN to accelerate the loading speed and save the bandwidth of user avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways have their advantages.

Storing images in the file system is of great advantage for applications that have:

- Small and simple logic
- Images that are static and doesn’t change very often
- No concern for security
- Extremely large images such as maps

Storing images in SQL Server is of great advantage for applications that have:

- Highly sensitive image data such as medical x-rays or court evidence where security is extremely important
- High availability requirements
- Maintainability requirements
- Very large size (such as a HR system with more than 200,000 employees with very fast movement of such as rehire and resignation)